# Navigation Drawer сбросить фон выбранного элемента

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

необходимо сбросить (фон) выбранного пункта меню, то есть было так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А сделать вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Решение, может кому пригодится:

```
navigationView.getCheckedItem().setChecked(false);
```